# Need an address with all Selenium versions available for download

Tags: selenium

I need a site that contains all Selenium versions, so i can download whichever libraries i want. Does anyone know such a site?

Thanks,
Tudor

Answer (score 2):

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html - Selenium webdriver versions. Use maven or some similar tool, put in the version number and it gets downloaded to your project

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for below

https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/versions

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver

Comment: I need the libraries for windows, not .gem or .nupkg, i need archives.